# Finding f(0) and f(1) of f(x) of a certain integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to find $F(0)$ and $F'(1)$ where $F(x) = \int_0^{x^2} (t^3+3)dt$

I know the answer is $F(0) = 0$ and $F'(1)=8$

but how would you get to that answer.

I might be wrong but maybe find anti-derivative of the $(t^3+3)$? But what would I do with the $x^2$ .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Substitute $x=0$ or $x=1$ into the integral...

Comment: My mistake I meant $F'(1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\dfrac{t^4}{4}+3t$ is an antiderivative, you have
$$
F(x)=\int_0^{x^2}(t^3+3)\,dt=
\left[\dfrac{t^4}{4}+3t\right]_0^{x^2}=
\frac{(x^2)^4}{4}+3x^2
$$
Can you do $F(1)$? (Hint: it is not $8$.)

---

Probably the question is asking you for $F'(1)$, which is a different thing; by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule,
$$
F'(x)=((x^2)^3+3)\cdot 2x
$$
and indeed you have $F'(0)=0$ and $F'(1)=8$.

Comment: Yeah I meant $F'(1)$, thanks for noticing and for the answer.

Comment: Btw, how did you get the $2x$?

Comment: @shawnedward Let $u=x^2$,
$$\begin{align*}
F'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2}(t^3+t)\ dt\\
&= \frac{d}{du} \int_0^{u}(t^3+t)\ dt \cdot \frac{du}{dx}\\
&= (u^3+u)\cdot\frac{du}{dx}
\end{align*}$$